# Count no.of characters in a string without spaces and special characters?

Tags: php, string

We have `strlen` and `mb_strlen` of the count the string but that give the  all the characters in the string . I want to count only character [a-z][A-Z] in the given string is there any per defined function .Or we need to develop our own logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Tested**

The following regex replaces all numbers, symbols & spaces. Shortly saying.. it will allow only alphabets `A-Z` and `a-z`, others won't be taken into account.

```
<?php
$str='Hello World345345 *90234 $$5assd54';
$str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/","",$str);
echo $str;//HelloWorldassd
echo strlen($str);//14
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll need to use your own logic. If you're only interested in counting a-z and A-Z then this should work:

```
<?php
$string= 'This is my sample string.';

echo "Everything: ".strlen($string);
echo '<br />';
echo "Only alphabetical: ".strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $string));
?>
```

Basically that's just removing everything that isn't in our allowed characters list then counting the characters in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expressions, and the fact that `preg_match_all` returns the number of matches. Why RE? Because you may often have to add new chars to translate in order to count the actual size.

```
<?php

$str = ' this is my String with spécial chars';
echo strlen($str) . "\n";

echo preg_match_all ('/[A-Za-z]/', $str, $out) . "\n" ;
```

Produces `38` and `29`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = explode( ' ',$sentence ); 

$words = count( $word );
```

Comment: This is good for taking out spaces, but other whitespace characters won't be taken out.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write your custom code like this

```
<?php
$x = "rahul";
$len = strlen($x);
$myLen = 0;
for($i =0; $i < $len ; $i++) {
  if(!( $x[$i]==" " || $x[$i]=="/" || $x[$i]=="&" )) { // Add more conditions here
    $myLen++;
  }
}
```