# How do i get the length of a string except a character in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string called line and it has 5 characters.

`line = 1,2,3`

the strlen() function gave me the answer as 5. but i need to count the number of characters except ','. how should i do it ?

Comment: Use `str_replace()` to remove all the `,` characters, and get the length of the result.

Comment: @Barmar how do i remove it? could you please help me

Comment: I just told you, use `str_replace()`.

Comment: @Barmar can you help me with a example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count no.of characters in a string without spaces and special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604520/count-no-of-characters-in-a-string-without-spaces-and-special-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use explode

```
$values = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'; // Your values in array
$str_array = explode(',', $values); //Explode string or numbers between commas in array

$size = count($str_array);// count string or numbers in array
echo $size; //Get total
```

To get total sum of numbers in array :

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    print_r(array_sum($numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
$line = "1,2,3";
echo  strlen(str_replace(',', '', $line));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fir replace , with '' and then count.

```
$line = "1,2,3";
$new_line = str_replace(',', '', $line);
echo  strlen($new_line);
```