# How can I use variables with update query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$b=number_format($number[12],2);
$sql01=mysql_query("UPDATE t_maindbfordashboard SET valueVar=".$a." WHERE managementName=dds");
```

I am absolutely sure that there are no problems connecting to the database or such. This query works when I try "SELECT * FROM tableName". Where do you think I'm making a mistake?

Comment: `$b` vs `$a`! Also, use prepared statements

Comment: You use $a and $a is not defined any where in your code

Comment: Try to explode numbers see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818549/12232340

Answer (score 2):

Ask if you need more help, and side note be careful with the sql, yours can be injected.

```php
$b=number_format($number[12],2);
$sql01= $MysqliHandler->prepare('UPDATE t_maindbfordashboard SET valueVar=? WHERE managementName="dds"');
$sql01->bind_param('s', $b); //you typed $a here but where is that value from? guess its $b?
$sql01->execute();
$sql01->close();
```

Comment: this wont help he needs explode numbers from array

Comment: @Dilek Why does he need to explode numbers? What numbers?

Comment: @kerbholz he is trying to insert more than 1 number, not only one number

Comment: @Dilek Says who? `$number[12]` most likely is just one number

Comment: you think the `$number[12]`? so it should be `$b = explode("', '", $b)`

Comment: @MadsSander No, your code looks fine to me, no need to explode anything

Comment: yes @MadsSander I think he is trying to update with multi values in array, would be nice if he could talk :)

Comment: @Dilek What makes you think he's trying to update with multiple values? If `$number[12]` weren't a `float` he should be getting a `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float ...` warning

Comment: @kerbholz he probably does *Where do you think I'm making a mistake?* nvm he cant explain anyway I might be wrong.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to answer poorly written questions. Your answer might be helpful, but the question is unclear and unless edited into shape it will be deleted in few days.